# "pl00092": Null Value:No assertions in reply from IDP

Tags: java, single-sign-on, jboss6.x, adfs3.0, picketlink

I have configured `ADFS 3.0` with my `JBoss 6.1.0_final` which using `JDK6`

The setup is successful and when I access application URL it redirects me to adfs page. After successful login in adfs it redirect to my application URL, Here error I encountered an error is

```
ERROR [org.picketlink.identity.federation] Service Provider could not handle the request.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PL00092: Null Value:No assertions in reply from IDP
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.DefaultPicketLinkLogger.samlHandlerNoAssertionFromIDP(DefaultPicketLinkLogger.java:1410) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AuthenticationHandler$SPAuthenticationHandler.handleStatusResponseType(SAML2AuthenticationHandler.java:415) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AuthenticationHandler.handleStatusResponseType(SAML2AuthenticationHandler.java:135) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.process.SAMLHandlerChainProcessor.callHandlerChain(SAMLHandlerChainProcessor.java:64) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.process.ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.processHandlersChain(ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.java:105) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.process.ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.process(ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.java:86) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.tomcat.sp.AbstractSPFormAuthenticator.handleSAMLResponse(AbstractSPFormAuthenticator.java:448) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.tomcat.sp.AbstractSPFormAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractSPFormAuthenticator.java:324) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.tomcat.sp.AbstractSPFormAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractSPFormAuthenticator.java:252) [:2.1.8.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:559) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
```

My picketlink.xml is

```
    <PicketLink xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:config:2.1">
    <PicketLinkSP xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:config:2.1"
        ServerEnvironment="tomcat" BindingType="POST" SupportsSignatures="true" CanonicalizationMethod="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <KeyProvider
            ClassName="org.picketlink.identity.federation.core.impl.KeyStoreKeyManager">
            <Auth Key="KeyStoreURL" Value="server.keystore" />
            <Auth Key="KeyStorePass" Value="changeit" />
            <Auth Key="SigningKeyPass" Value="changeit" />
            <Auth Key="SigningKeyAlias" Value="jbosskey" />
            <ValidatingAlias Key="{APPLICATION-URL}" Value="digite" />
            <ValidatingAlias Key="{ADFS-URL}" Value="digite" />
        </KeyProvider>

    </PicketLinkSP>
    <Handlers xmlns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:handler:config:2.1">
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2LogOutHandler" />
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AuthenticationHandler" >
        <Option Key="NAMEID_FORMAT" Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"/>
        <Option Key="CLOCK_SKEW_MILIS" Value="3600000"/></Handler>
        <Handlerv class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.RolesGenerationHandler" />
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2SignatureGenerationHandler" ></Handler>
        <Handler class="org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2AttributeHandler">
        <Option Key="ATTRIBUTE_CHOOSE_FRIENDLY_NAME" Value="true"/>
        </Handler>
    </Handlers>
</PicketLink>
```

**Update1:** 
The error on ADFS is

```
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = Microsoft.IdentityServer.Tokens.MSISSecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
'. Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.ResolveSigningCredentials()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.OnEndOfRootElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadAuthnRequest(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadSamlMessage(XmlReader reader, NamespaceContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String encodedSamlMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage message)
```

I have tried following solutions found on internet with no luck.

1. `Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –TargetName “Name property of your RP Trust” –SigningCertificateRevocationCheck “None”`
2. Entity ID in `sp-metadata.xml` and in RP must be same

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both sign methods values are the same. Picketlink always sets the value of Signature SIGN METHOD to w3.org redardless of the value set when using a REDIRECT binding type and ADFS needs both sign methods to be the same for the communication to work successfully.

Comment: on ADFS side we get `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier` this error